# Undefined control sequence with nested fraction

Tags: fractions, undefined

I got a block like this

```
\hspace*{\fill}
        \text {$O(R\mid \vec{x} ,\vec{q} $ = $\cfrac{P(R=1\mid \vec{x},\vec{q})}{P(R=0\mid \vec{x},\vec{q})}$ = $\cfrag{\cfrag{P(R=1\mid \vec{q})P(\vec{x} \mid R=1, \vec{q})}{P(\vec{x} \mid \vec{q})}   }{3}$}
\hspace*{\fill}
```

Latex shows that the line in the middle has an Undefined control sequence and the nested fractions dont show up properly.

What did i do here wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: For a starter, do you know `\centering` and the `center` environment?

Comment: Also, do you know math environments?

Comment: a fraction is not a fragtion ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you I realized that too, it works now :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is a simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a proper math environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\hspace*{\fill}
        \text {$O(R\mid \vec{x} ,\vec{q} $ = $\cfrac{P(R=1\mid \vec{x},\vec{q})}{P(R=0\mid \vec{x},\vec{q})}$ = $\cfrac{\cfrac{P(R=1\mid \vec{q})P(\vec{x} \mid R=1, \vec{q})}{P(\vec{x} \mid \vec{q})}   }{3}$}
\hspace*{\fill}

\begin{equation*}
        O(R\mid \vec{x} ,\vec{q}  =
 \cfrac{P(R=1\mid \vec{x},\vec{q})}{P(R=0\mid \vec{x},\vec{q})} =
 \cfrac{\cfrac{P(R=1\mid \vec{q})P(\vec{x} \mid R=1, \vec{q})}{P(\vec{x} \mid \vec{q})}   }{3}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized it was a typo \cfrag instead of \cfrac , dummy